# How to handle special characters in SQL table name when generating SQL from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am developing a PHP tool to do some database operations. I am facing a problem now. I can't make the proper query if the table name contains a special character, I know it's a rare situation.

For example please see the following query

```
INSERT INTO `@#$%."'"12-}.+/_*-ttr*` (`id`, `obj`, `value`) 
        VALUES (NULL, 'hi', 'ttt');
```

I want to assign a table name to a PHP variable `$table_name` & I want to execute this query.

```
$query= "insert in to `{$table_name}` " (`id`, `obj`, `value`) 
                VALUES (NULL, 'hi', 'ttt')
```

How can I properly assign table name to $table_name properly? Due to special characters in table name I am getting errors.

Please note the table name I have given is very very rare but I want to make my code suitable for all situations.

Copyright for this question goes to [Abilash Erikson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7850364/abilash-erikson) from his [morphed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207485).
I opened a new Question to preserve my answer as of [meta comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412224/i-answered-a-question-which-was-replaced-by-a-totally-different-one)

Comment: WHY On earth would you want to have a table name with all those odd characters, why are you making probelms for yourself

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html), you are allowed to use nearly any char within the ticks you use.

> Identifiers are converted to Unicode internally. They may contain
> these characters:
>
> - Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>   ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
>   Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF
> - Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000:
>   ASCII: U+0001 .. U+007F
>   Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

To get the table name into the query you just could string concatenation like so:

```
$query = "insert into `" . $table_name . "` (`id`, `obj`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, 'hi', 'ttt');";
```

ATTENTION: this is super dangerous because it opens an attack surface to SQL injection if the table name could be controlled from a user (admin panel,...)

To prevent this just escape all ticks ` from the tablename (since all other chars are allowed and encapsulated)

```
$table_name = str_replace("`","``", $table_name);
$query = "insert into `" . $table_name . "` (`id`, `obj`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, 'hi', 'ttt');";
```

Fiddle can be seen [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c6e21cdcd806f7fa3ad44ab7973af33e4fa08e8a)